# Google PostGIS - ogr2ogr unable to open datasource

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, postgis, google-cloud-sql

I have this kml file

https://pastebin.com/vyTqwxin

Stored on a bucket On Google Cloud Platform

I'm trying to import it to a Google Cloud PostgreSQL table.
The table is empty and doesn't have any column set.

I'm using this command:

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname='mydb' host='localhost' port='5432' user='myuser' password='mypass'" gs://bucket-name/data.kml
```

It returns this error:

> Unable to open datasource 'gs://bucket-name/data.kml' with the following drivers: ...

Is there another way to import kml data to GCP SQL?
Where am I wrong?

Comment: I looked at the ogr2ogr command (googled) but couldn't find a description of the source file parameter format.  Examples I saw seem to say that it is a local file.  Can it be specified as an http URL?  If so, then use the full external URL to your object in GCS as opposed to the "gs://" prefix which is only known to a small number of programs (primarily GCP programs).

Comment: it's a file stored on Google Cloud storage... the path should be like that.

Comment: My loose understanding is that "gs://" is a Google made up URL prefix (compare with http:// or ftp://) and that the program interpreting the URL would have to have knowledge that "gs://" means use GCS API to access the data when it sees such.  Do we think ogr2ogr knows about GCS?  If it knows about http:// then there is a 1-1 mapping between a GCS object and an HTTP object.

Comment: @Kolban I understand what you mean... I'll try with a local copy of the kml file and I 'll let you know

Comment: Gotcha ... it all depends on where you want the kml file processed from.  Ideally you want it read directly from GCS storage but if that is not possible, you can copy the file using gsutil to your local directory, process it there and then delete the local (temporary) copy.

Comment: gdal/ogr doesn't understand `gs://` protocol. copy the file first, or set up `gcsfuse`